# How to check if a foreign key referencing multiple columns was created with MATCH FULL or MATCH SIMPLE constraint?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

I came across a foreign key which references two columns (which form a composite primary key of another table) in a PostgeSQL 10 database. How can I check if this foreign key uses MATCH FULL or MATCH SIMPLE constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find that in the `confmatchtype` column of [`pg_constraint`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/catalog-pg-constraint.html):

> Foreign key match type: f = full, p = partial, s = simple

Comment: The foreign key was declared as MATCH SIMPLE and I updated the `confmatchtype` column from `s` to `f` and tested it. The updated constraint did work as expected but I guess it's a bad idea to change system catalogs. Is there any other way to change a foreign key declared as MATCH SIMPLE to MATCH FULL apart from dropping and recreating the same?

Comment: You definitely should not modify the catalogs - you could easily end up with an invalid constraint. Yes, you would have to drop and re-create the constraint to effect that change. Remember that the validity of the constraint has to be checked.

Comment: @AbhishekPathak Please ask a new (clear researched non-duplicate) question in a new post.